# Hive metastore's JDBC URL setup with mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc, hive

Below is the URL I am using in hive-site.xml to connect to mysql.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_db?autoReconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false;useSSL=true
```

Somehow, it errors out with the following error.

> The connection property 'verifyServerCertificate' only accepts values
>   of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value
>   'false;useSSL=true' is not in this set.

This was the same URL with which I ran the schematool and it ran all good.

Let me know if there are any suggestions for URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just figured out the solution.

We need to use

```
> & amp ; ( no spaces included ) in the JDBC URL
```

Below is what worked for me:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_db?autoReconnect=true&
amp;verifyServerCertificate=false& amp;useSSL=true
```

( remember to remove spaces after &, I had to add space so that it gets displayed on this HTML page )

Hope this helps.

Regards

Abhay Dandekar